# Joining 2 pandas dataframes with multiple condition, 1 condition is based on a static string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a function to solve the following problem. I have a panda dataframe (df_1) which looks like this.

```
     Model      Type  Amount
0  Model 1     Price   10000
1  Model 1       Tax    2000
2  Model 1  Discount     500
3  Model 2     Price   20000
4  Model 2       Tax    4000
5  Model 3     Price   50000
```

I then created a new dataframe (df_new) from the unique values of df_1

```
df_new = df_1.drop_duplicates(subset='Model', keep="first")

columns = ['Type', 'Amount']
df_new.drop(columns, inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Now, I want to add on to the new dataframe. First, I added more columns. Now, I want to fill each column in a similar way to Excel's vLookUp formula or index + match. I have to match 2 criteria, the Model from my df_new but also a string. In my example the string that I want to match with is "Tax", "Discount"... but there could be more.

In the end, my df_new should look like this.

```
     Model  Price   Tax Discount
0  Model 1  10000  2000      500
1  Model 2  20000  4000      NAN
2  Model 3  50000   NAN      NAN
```

I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.
Thank you so much. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) is what you are after :

```
df.pivot("Model", "Type", "Amount")

Type    Discount    Price   Tax
Model           
Model 1 500.0   10000.0     2000.0
Model 2 NaN     20000.0     4000.0
Model 3 NaN     50000.0     NaN
```

If you need it to be exactly as your data output above, a few more steps are required :

```
(df
 .pivot("Model", "Type", "Amount")
 .reindex(df.Type.unique(), axis=1)
 .rename_axis(columns=None)
 .reset_index())

   Model    Price   Tax     Discount
0   Model 1 10000.0 2000.0  500.0
1   Model 2 20000.0 4000.0  NaN
2   Model 3 50000.0 NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This approach worked out for me.